200 amp breaker tripping
I started my dryer before I went to bed. I noticed the dryer quit and the breaker tripped.
Before that it was the breaker box on the pole outside, the breaker inside the house (200amp) and it was hot.
When I unplugged the dryer it stopped tripping. All this started when the dryer broke down and I put a belt on. Could it be the dryer is fried? It's 24 years old and thinking of replacing it. .

I tried to add some formatting, sentence structure, capitalization, and punctuation, to try to make this more understandable. FWIW I cannot parse the meaning of the part I italicized. Is the 200 amp breaker inside or outside? Also, please post pictures of your circuit breaker panels and labels. Use the Edit link to add pictures using the Mountain icon. And please edit the italicized part to say what you wanted it to mean.

Fried, but maybe not completely.  You will have to look.  From what I have read, the newer stuff does not seem to be built as well.

Can you post photos of your breaker panels please?

They make a neat thing called a heat pump dryer.  It takes very little power, saving you about a buck a load on electricity, and very importantly, eliminating the dryer vent!  No longer sucking outside air in which you need to spend money conditioning. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zheQKmAT_a0&t=940s

A short circuit can allow a LOT of current through for a short period of time. Because of that, any/all breakers between the short circuit (e.g., insider your dryer) and the utility can trip. Most of the time, a small breaker (e.g., 30A for a dryer) will trip very quickly, so that the larger breaker (e.g., 200A typical main breaker) will not trip. There are limits to the capacity of small (e.g, 10 AWG typical for a 30A dryer circuit) but there is definitely a range of time/current where enough current can flow to trip a 200A breaker.
Every breaker has a trip curve. This shows how fast a breaker trips at the design current (typically takes several minutes or more) vs. 2x or 3x or more, to the top level where a breaker will trip within 1 cycle. In this situation, the short circuit was may have been big and so fast that it tripped the 200A breaker at the same time as it normally would have tripped the 30A breaker.
However, such a fast trip would not normally heat up the 200A breaker very much. Which makes me concerned that the 30A breaker is truly faulty. Any breaker can fail, but they are normally designed to be extremely reliable due to their role in safety. But certain types, such as certain Federal Pacific and Challenger breakers, are known to fail catastrophically - not tripping when they are supposed to, either tripping much later than they should or not tripping at all! If, for example, a short circuit allows 400A (2x the 200A rating), it could take anywhere from 45 seconds to 6 minutes (based on a rough examination of Eaton BR Trip Curves and other brands are likely similar) to trip. That will cause some heating, but the breaker will trip in time to prevent your house from burning down. Except that the 30A wire may overheat and literally burn up while waiting for the main breaker to trip. That same 400A on a properly functioning 30A breaker would trip in under 2 seconds.
CHECK YOUR BRANCH CIRCUIT BREAKERS AND DRYER WIRING At a minimum, the 30A breaker should be considered as damaged and replaced, even if not a known problem type. In addition, the dryer wiring, receptacle box and the dryer itself should be checked end-to-end for signs of damage - melted insulation, burn marks, etc. and replaced as needed.
If the 30A breaker is a known problem type then the entire panel and all breakers need to be checked. In certain cases you may have a mix of good and bad breaker types in an otherwise good panel. In certain cases you may have an actual bad panel. Pictures would help figure that out.
